# save a scraped text in csv so that could be opened in excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv, web-scraping

I've put together a scraper for a list of links like [this](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1019671/000156459020017461/0001564590-20-017461.txt)

Everythings works fine and I get a dataframe with all the data I want, included the full text of the page in a column ("Filing_FullText").

The .csv I export works perfectly if I reopen it in python, but in excel the structure is totally compromised. I thought it was because of line breaks in the text and I've tried solutions such as:

`DF = DF.replace({r'\\n': ''}, regex=True)`

but still can't get it to work.
Here you can see a snapshot of the working dataframe and how badly it looks in excel, and of the csv opened in a text editor: 
[image: screenshots]

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Is it possible you are hitting the character limits for a cell in Excel? Are any of the cells in "Filling_FullText" > 32,767 ([Excel Limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)). One way to check this is to open a blank Excel sheet, and then import the CSV, rather than trying to open it directly.

Comment: Please share a [mre].